# Nonnegativity of a term given that domain is convex

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to understand an argument that I've seen on two papers, which I do not fully understand but have a feeling for what is going on.

The claim is the following: Given that a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is bounded, smooth and convex, if for a smooth function $c$ we have $\frac{\partial c}{\partial \nu} = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$, then $\frac{ \partial}{\partial \nu} |\nabla c|^2 \leq 0$ on $\partial \Omega$.

I've seen that the last term is equal to $- II(\nabla c)$ (1), and that for convex domains the second fundamental form is positive definite (on $\mathbb{R}^3$) (2) and now from $\frac{\partial c}{\partial \nu} = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$, we have that $\nabla c$ only has a tangential component on the boundary.

How can I formalize the fact that $\nabla c$ going alongside $\partial \Omega$ is carrying the second form information on sign?

Just as an observation, I don't know much geometry so I might have made some mistakes and would also appreciate any correction.

(1):  Dal Passo, R., Garcke, H., Grün, G. (1998). On a fourth-order degenerate
parabolic equation: Global entropy estimates, existence, and qualitative
behavior of solutions. SIAM J. Math. Anal. 29:321–342.

(2): < [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302199/is-there-a-way-to-relate-convexity-to-gaussian-curvature/302207#302207>](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302199/is-there-a-way-to-relate-convexity-to-gaussian-curvature/302207#302207%3E)

Comment: Here is a proof: https://sunlimingbit.wordpress.com/2022/04/03/neumann-boundary-condition/

Comment: @JackT thank you so much!